# Spring WebMVC 4.3.3.Release + Spring Data 1.10.3 Release + Hibernate 5.2.2 Final + MySQL 5.7 - Multi-Tenancy Issue

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa, multi-tenant

I am trying to resolve a problem related to multi-tenancy of the SpringWebMVC application that is being developed.

Need to create a schema on the fly for every customer who signs up. Once they sign in, all the transactions that they do should be against that schema.

For this I tried to leverage the Hibernate 5 Multi-Tenancy. It works fine - till generating the schema per customer. The application starts with the common schema definition, creates all the entity tables there for the common schema as mentioned in `@Table` and then before populating the tables (using entity definitions for that schema) tries to insert the data to the `schema.table` and throws the error that the `schema.table` is not available.

I am using the class that extends `AbstractDataSourceBasedMultiTenantConnectionProviderImpl` to provide the `Environment.MULTI_TENANT_CONNECTION_PROVIDER` through object reference by `@Autowired` injection. The `CurrentTenantIdentifierResolver` interface is implemented by a class to provide the object reference to `Environment.MULTI_TENANT_IDENTIFIER_RESOLVER` through `@Autowired` injection.

Not sure why Hibernate / JPA provider is not able to populate the tables for the schema which is getting created on the fly. The JPAProperties are as below:

```
Properties jpaProperties = new Properties();
jpaProperties.put("javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action", "create-drop");
jpaProperties.put("javax.persistence.create-database-schemas", true);
jpaProperties.put(Environment.HBM2DDL_AUTO, "create-drop");
jpaProperties.put(Environment.DEFAULT_SCHEMA, "base_schema");
jpaProperties.put(Environment.MULTI_TENANT, "SCHEMA");
jpaProperties.put(Environment.MULTI_TENANT_IDENTIFIER_RESOLVER, applicationCurrentTenantIdentifierResolver);
jpaProperties.put(Environment.MULTI_TENANT_CONNECTION_PROVIDER, applicationMultiTenantConnectionProvider);
jpaProperties.put(Environment.FORMAT_SQL, true);
jpaProperties.put("spring.jpa.hibernate.naming_strategy", "org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy");
jpaProperties.put(Environment.USE_SQL_COMMENTS, true);
jpaProperties.put(Environment.GENERATE_STATISTICS, true);
jpaProperties.put("hbm2dll.create_namespaces", true);
```

And the `HibernateVendorAdapter` has the following values:

```
HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
vendorAdapter.setDatabasePlatform("org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect");
vendorAdapter.setShowSql(true);
vendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(true);
vendorAdapter.setDatabase(Database.MYSQL);
```

The POM has the following libraries:

Properties:

```
<properties>
  <project.mysql.connector.version>5.1.30</project.mysql.connector.version>
  <project.hibernate.version>5.2.2.Final</project.hibernate.version>
  <project.spring.orm.version>4.3.3.RELEASE</project.spring.orm.version>
  <project.spring.data.jpa.version>1.10.3.RELEASE</project.spring.data.jpa.version>
</properties>
```

And dependencies:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>mysql</groupId>
   <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
   <version>${project.mysql.connector.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
   <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
   <version>${project.hibernate.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
   <version>${project.spring.data.jpa.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
   <version>${project.spring.orm.version}</version>
</dependency>
```